# aws Lambda interruption

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

When I try to call the SQLConnection.Open() method, my aws lambda simply stops without errors. Why? 
But other lambdas not published by me are working.
I use the same Roles that other lambdas use.

```
using (var con = new SqlConnection("connection string"))
{       
    con.Open(); <-- interruption
using (var command = new SqlCommand($"sql command", con))
{
    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
con.Close();
}
```

project.json

```
{
"version": "1.0.0-*",
"buildOptions": {
},

"dependencies": {
"Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
"type": "platform",
"version": "1.0.0"
},
"Amazon.Lambda.Core": "1.0.0*",
"Amazon.Lambda.Serialization.Json": "1.1.0",
"Amazon.Lambda.Tools": {
"type": "build",
"version": "1.8.0"
},
"Models": "1.0.0-*",
"AmazonConfigurations": "1.0.0-*",
"MwsFeedService": "1.0.0-*",
"MwsProductService": "1.0.0-*",
"AWSSDK.Lambda": "3.3.6.2",
"Extensions": "1.0.0-*",
"System.Data.SqlClient": "4.1.0",
"System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeInformation": "4.0.0"
},
"tools": {
"Amazon.Lambda.Tools": "1.8.0"
},

"frameworks": {
"netcoreapp1.0": {
"imports": "dnxcore50"
}
}
}
```

Comment: It is probably hanging because it can't connect to the database for some reason. Did you place the Lambda function in a VPC? Is the database in on AWS, in a VPC?

Comment: Downvoters, you don't understand the question. Don't downvote until you do

Comment: please fix your indentation